# WP E-Commerce Billing Details / Purchase Logs blank?

Tags: wordpress, paypal, e-commerce

For some reason, when I make a purchase and go into Store Sales > Item, the Billing Details are blank. 
With the exception of **Purchase Log Date** which has the date of 1st Jan 1970 on every purchase?!

I am using WP E-Commerce and have tried PayPal Standard and PayPal Express options, and tried shipping address on and off.

Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

Thanks